# Optimizing LINQ within a large datatable

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable that has ~800,000 rows, and consists of 4 columns. StartLocation, EndLocation, Distance, and Zone. What I am trying to do is, for every record in that particular Zone, get the "opposite" record and see if the distance is less than the original. Every record in this DataTable will have one "opposite" record.

An example row and it's "opposite" looks like this:

```
StartLoc | EndLoc | Distance | Zone
 2, 1       4, 3     5         1
 4, 3       2, 1     4         1
```

---

The problem here is that the current solution is extremely time consuming and simple. The code below is the strategy employed now.

```
public DataTable ProcessTable(DataTable _tbl)
    {
        //copy the schema to new datatable
        DataTable ProcessedTable = _tbl.Clone();

        foreach (DataRow row in _tbl.Rows)
        {
            var ReverseRow = from DataRow revRow in _tbl.Rows
                             where revRow.Field<string>("StartLoc") == row.Field<string>("EndLoc")
                             where revRow.Field<string>("EndLoc") == row.Field<string>("StartLoc")
                             where revRow.Field<string>("Zone") == row.Field<string>("Zone")
                             select revRow;

            DataRow result = ReverseRow.First<DataRow>();

            int rowDistance = row.Field<int>("Distance");
            int resultDistance = result.Field<int>("Distance");

            if (resultDistance < rowDistance)
                row["Distance"] = resultDistance;

            ProcessedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }

        return ProcessedTable;
    }
```

---

I am a LINQ noobie, so this question will have 3 parts:

1. Is there any way I can speed up the inner query?
2. Can I consolidate the foreach loop and query to one elegant LINQ line, and also have it increase performance?
3. Am I looking at this completely wrong and need to change my approach?

Comment: Welcome.  This question might do better on another Stack Exchange site.  Perhaps _Code Review_?  Anyone?  Good luck!

Comment: Can you consider combinations of StartLoc/EndLoc/Zone unique? You could add a primary key on them and use Find for good performance.

Comment: It seems you can apply constraint StartLoc < EndLoc. You would have every pair only once and you do not need to solve data consistency problems.

Comment: if you get the DataTable from a database, the query should be done on the database instead of getting the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

Try a join.  You are cloning the entire table which may account for the slow speed

```
       public DataTable ProcessTable(DataTable _tbl)
        {
            //copy the schema to new datatable

            var query = from r1 in _tbl.AsEnumerable()
                        from r2 in _tbl.AsEnumerable() 
                        where (r1.Field<string>("StartLoc") == r2.Field<string>("EndLoc"))
                           && (r1.Field<string>("EndLoc") == r2.Field<string>("StartLoc"))
                           && (r1.Field<string>("Zone") == r2.Field<string>("Zone")) 
                        select new { r1 = r1, r2 = r2 };

            DataTable processedTable = query.Where(x => x.r1.Field<int>("Distance") < x.r2.Field<int>("Distance"))
                                             .Select(x => x.r1)
                                             .CopyToDataTable();

            return processedTable;
        }
```

Comment: Basically that's it. However to make it precise, you might consider adding the other conditions from the OP query to the join (also showing OP how to perform composite key join).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I am now getting an out of memory exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try getting only one zone at time.  Or go back to the slow method.  If data is from a SQL Server using a stored procedure wold be faster.

Comment: The query is missing essential conditions, if he tries it in this form no wonder it returns nonsense or even crash. Ivan Stoev already pointed to this.

Comment: Antonin: Please explain what you think is wrong.  Ivan just said it could have more details.  I left the query to be general purposely to make it easy to understand. Then added additional filtering in the linq statement.  There is nothing wrong with the code.  The real issue is there are more than 800,00 rows in the table.

Comment: OP has three conditions in the join : `a.StartLoc==b.EndLoc`, `a.EndLoc==b.StartLoc`, `a.Zone==b.Zone`. You have only the first. You are not comparing every record with the opposite record, but with many more records. Instead of 400000 pairs you can have easily like 400000000 pairs and what is worst, the results are not correct.

Comment: Ok, I made changes